# How to upgrade from asp.net core 1x to asp.net core 2 dual authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, entity-framework-core

I have the following dual authentication in asp.net core, JWT for api and identity for MVC, and also some authorization. Looks like core 2 has changed alot, I get errors after upgrading and I don't know how to shift the code. Please help. Thank you. Following is the startup.cs code(working for asp.net core 1x):

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)

            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)

            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
             Configuration = builder.Build();
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()

            .MinimumLevel
            .Warning()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile("Logs/GateKeeperLog-{Date}.txt")
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<GkEnterpriseContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Database:Connection"]));
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GkEnterpriseContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            }).AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

            });

        services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy("GkDevices",
                policy => policy
                    .RequireClaim("family_name", "GkDevice"));

        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }


       JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/api")

        , builder =>
        {
            builder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audidence"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
                        (JwtTokenIssuer.PrivateKey)),
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    SaveSigninToken = true,

                    NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName
              }

            });


        });

        app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/v2/computers/")

            , coxt =>

                coxt.MapWhen((ctx) =>
                {

                    var deviceName = ctx.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName)?.Value ?? "";
                    var testPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString($"/api/v2/computers/{deviceName}");

                    var pathMatch = ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(testPath);
                    return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceName) || !pathMatch;


                }, cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Run((req) =>
                    {
                        req.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        return req.Response.WriteAsync("Sorry, you cannot access this resource...");
                    });
                }));


        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCodes/{0}");
        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "defaultApi",
                template: "api/v2/{controller}/{id?}");
        });




    }
```

Comment: You can't use branching anymore with the new system. Now, you should set the default scheme for the majority of the application and for the rest use the scheme proeprty of `AuthorizeAttribute` and in response challanges

Comment: Its frustrating, I don't even know where to start

Comment: Start with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x) and the [official announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262). It's as simple as putting `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` (for example) on your actions. That's what these sources are for

Comment: You are correct, I did as you and documentation say, but the problem is where I was to check whether or not the api/v2/computer/{name} is same as name that is in issued jwt. Everything is working fine except that part.

Comment: That issuer part isn't part of your initial question. You should be more specific in future. Your question is how to upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2 Auth, not how to handle different issuers. You're well advise to ask a **new** question about that specifics and more details